# How do I prevent Entity Framework Core tools 2.1.4 making modifications to the target project file?

Tags: entity-framework, scaffolding, ef-core-2.1

When running `Scaffold-DbContext` the `.csproj` for the target project is modified to include a new `<ItemGroup>` containing a `<Compile Include="path\model-file.cs">` for each Model generated. This behavior is new to version Entity Framework Core tools 2.1.4 and not desired. Previous version did not do this. How do I prevent this behavior?

Comment: Well I'd say for *most* people it would be the desired behavior, why wouldn't you want the generated models to be part of your project? If I were you, I'd just use my source control to undo the changes to the csproj file.

Comment: Sounds like you're using a classic .NET Framework project and not one of the new SDK projects. With a classic project, you have to reverence every code file.